# Skip rules in form if element is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to skip validation with a dropdown if it's hidden

`<select name="year" class="ui fluid selection dropdown year" multiple="" id="multi-select-year" ></select>`

```
<script>
    $('.ui form')
        .form({
            on: 'blur',
            fields: {
                'multi-select-year': {
                    identifier: 'multi-select-year',

                    rules: [
                        {
                            type: 'empty',
                            prompt: 'Please type title'
                        }
                    ]
                },
</script>
```

I want it to not trigger a prompt when the multi-select-year dropdown is hidden

Comment: Look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42881604/7114447) hope with helps.